# Grab a value from an attribute and make it available to controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to grab a simple value from a page attribute or something similar, but I'm looking for an elegant way to do so. I want to store this simple string somewhere common for controllers and services to use. I tried making a simple attribute:

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" site-section="home"> ... </div>
```

js:

```
...
.directive('siteSection', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $rootScope.siteSection = attrs.siteSection;
    }
  }
}]);
```

In that link function I can either save the string to a simple service (or value provider would be more acceptable for this sort of thing) but that link function is called after the controller functions, so when the controller initializes my value is not there.

So what's an elegant way to do something like this? I'd rather not use ng-init as those can get messy.

Comment: Do you really need directive for that? I think you should create your global variable inside Configuration Block or Run Block. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Are you trying to *save* a value in the controller based on a text string from your directive attribute? http://plnkr.co/edit/cpx3oFVCO1AKouJ8ecE9?p=preview Or are you trying to parse the value on your directive attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$timeout` service to wait for angular like this :

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.siteSection = attrs.siteSection;
    }, 0);
}
```

Or the use `scope.$apply`

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        $rootScope.siteSection = attrs.siteSection;
    });
}
```

I also don't think you need to inject `$rootScope` cause you can access it using `scope.$root`

Comment: Tried this, I still have the problem of the controller scope being initialized before the link function is run.

Comment: Yes, the controller will be initialized before your directive but the siteSection value will be updated just after that

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing... I put the attribute on the root element then accessed `$rootElement` in a factory.

```
...
.factory('currentSection', ['$rootElement', function($rootElement) {

  return $rootElement.attr('site-section');

}]);
```

It felt better to have it as a provider here instead of sticking it in the scope. And I'm using $rootElement but not doing any DOM manipulation so I'm fine with that. May be overkill to put in a factory but this works great!